# Text alignment with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

[image: referance image]

Hi, i am trying to make alignment like the referance image above.

I can't modify the Jüri Üyeleri, Başkan and Üye sections as i want. With using tikz, how can i do?

Thank you.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=30mm,top=30mm,right=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{mathptmx} 
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tikz}               
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}    
\usepackage{longtable} 
\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\singlespacing %Satır bitimlerinde (\\) tek boşluk bırakır.
     \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
            every node/.style = {align=center}, font=\bfseries
                                ]
         \coordinate (cpn) at (current page.north);
         \node[below= 3.5cm of cpn] {TEKNİK ÜNİVERSİTESİ\\ FEN BİLİMLERİ ENSTİTÜSÜ};
         \node[below=10.4cm of cpn] {başlıklı bu çalışma 10/5/2019 gün ve 654 sayılı\\kararıyla oluşturulan jüri tarafından yapılan sınava\\YÜKSEK LİSANS TEZİ\\olarak kabul edilmiştir.};
        \node[below=16.7cm of cpn] {Jüri Üyeleri};
        \node[below=18.2cm of cpn] {Başkan  : Prof. Dr. John DOE . . . . . . . . };
        \node[below=19.4cm of cpn] {Üye     : Doç. Johnie DOEDOE . . . . . . . . };
        \node[below=20.6cm of cpn] {Üye     : Dr. Johnnn DOEKOER . . . . . . . . };
     \end{tikzpicture}
\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Comment: You do not need `tikz` here. Why not arrange the bottom lines as a `tabular`.

Comment: I am very new on Latex. Can u give an example for tabular please? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example. Quick and dirty.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[turkish,english,shorthands=:!]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}

\vspace{10cm}

\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}p{0.1cm}p{4.5cm} p{8cm}}
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Jüri Üyeleri}\\
Baskan & : &Prof. Dr. John DOE &\dotfill\\[1cm]
Üye    & : &Doç. Johnie DOEDOE &\dotfill\\
Üye    & : &Dr. Johnnn DOEKOER &\dotfill\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working now. Is there any way to align the table from the top? Like tikz?

Comment: Hi again @Denis. Is there any way to set the space between Juri Üyeleri and Başkan or Başkan and Üye?

Comment: @volkanyazici see above edit. Please consider accepting the answer if it suits you.